# json: unsupported type: func() time.Time Marshaling CreatedAt, UpdatedAt and DeletedAt

Tags: go, go-gorm

How can I resolve the error `json: unsupported type: func() time.Time` trying to return a newly saved model back as JSON.

```
user := database.DBConn.Create(&newUser)
return c.Status(http.StatusCreated).JSON(user) // fiber response
```

Tried ignoring the timestamp fields.

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    ID uuid.UUID `gorm:"primary_key;type:uuid;default:uuid_generate_v4()"`
    Phone     string `json:"phone"`
    FirstName string `json:"firstName"`
    LastName  string `json:"lastName"`
    Email string `json:"email"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `json:"-"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `json:"-"`
    DeletedAt time.Time `json:"-"`
}
```

Also tried

```
CreatedAt time.Time `gorm:"type:timestamp" json:"created_at,string,omitempty"`
UpdatedAt time.Time `gorm:"type:timestamp" json:"updated_at,string,omitempty"`
DeletedAt time.Time `gorm:"type:timestamp" json:"deleted_at,string,omitempty"`
```

And

```
CreatedAt time.Time `gorm:"type:datetime" json:"created_at,string,omitempty"`
UpdatedAt time.Time `gorm:"type:datetime" json:"updated_at,string,omitempty"`
DeletedAt time.Time `gorm:"type:datetime" json:"deleted_at,string,omitempty"`
```

Using gorm v1.20.12 and Go 1.15.6

Comment: Why are you attempting to marshal [`*gorm.DB`](https://pkg.go.dev/gorm.io/gorm#DB.Create)?

Comment: it's the result of calling the Create method on the db instance returned from calling gorm.open. in the documentation it looks like `result := db.Create(&user)`. in my case the db instance is called `database.DBConn`.

Comment: The result of `Create` is of type `*gorm.DB`.

Comment: why don't you try `return c.Status(http.StatusCreated).JSON(newUser)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I encountered similar error and discovered that `user := database.DBConn.Create(&newUser)` returns a *gorm.DB which cannot be marshaled by JSON.

Instead use this:

```golang
database.DBConn.Create(&newUser)
return c.Status(http.StatusCreated).JSON(newUser)
```

It worked for me and I hope it works for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers stated that .Create() returns *gorm.DB, so you have to know what causes this error.
You should return error this way:

```
if err:= database.DBConn.Create(&newUser).Error; if err != nil {
 return c.Status(fiber.StatusBadRequest).JSON(err.Error()) 
}
```